# remove numbers from string using python

Tags: python

hello I have a question:
How can I remove numbers from string, I know that the fasted and best way is to use translate

```
'hello467'.translate(None, '0123456789')
```

will return `hello`, but what if I want to remove only numbers that are not attached to a sting for example: `'the 1rst of every month I spend 10 dollars'` should be `'the 1rst of every month I spend dollars'` and not `'the rst of every month I spend  dollars'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

s = "the 1rst of every month I spend 10 dollars"
 
result = re.sub(r"\b\d+\b", '', s)
result = re.sub("  ", ' ', result)
```

should give:

```
the 1rst of every month I spend dollars
```

Comment: In some cases, `\b` might be better than `\s` e.g. to catch `I have 10.` Though in others, it would be worse e.g. `I have $10`

Comment: @match correct!

Comment: is the string starts with a number it can't work

Comment: @salmamasoaudi try the edited code

Answer (score 0):

Split the string and check if the element is a digit and if not then join it to the result.

```
str = ("the 1rst of every month I spend 10 dollars").split(' ')
result = ' '.join([i for i in str if not i.isdigit()])
print(result)
```

Comment: i dont wanna use any loop, i don't if i can use translate

Comment: if lambda function works for you then you can try `result = " ".join(filter(lambda x: not x.isdigit(), str))`